# Streamlines for irregular spaced wind data in R?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, polyline

I have got wind data for some stations. The data includes station latitude, longitude, wind speed and wind direction for each station in a csv file. This data is not regularly spaced data. I have a requirement to draw streamlines for this data in R language.

I tried couple of packages `rasterVis` for `STREAMPLOT()`, `TeachingDemos` for `My.Symbols` by searching through internet, however I was not successful.

Here is an example plot I was talking about. 
http://wx.gmu.edu/dev/clim301/850stream.png

Also here is some sample data from csv file that I got for which I was trying to draw streamlines.

```
longitude,latitude,windspeed,winddirection  
84.01,20,1.843478261,126.6521739  
77.13,28.48,3.752380952,138.952381  
77.2,28.68,2.413333333,140.2666667  
78.16,31.32,1.994444444,185.0555556  
77.112,31.531,2.492,149.96  
77,28.11,7.6,103  
77.09,31.5,1.752631579,214.8947368  
76.57,31.43,1.28,193.6  
77.02,32.34,3.881818182,264.4545455  
77.15,28.7,2.444,146.12  
77.35,30.55,3.663157895,131.3684211  
75.5,29.52,4.175,169.75  
72.43,24.17,2.095,279.3  
76.19,25.1,1.816666667,170  
76.517,30.975,1.284210526,125.6315789  
76.13,28.8,4.995,126.7  
75.04,29.54,4.09,151.85  
72.3,24.32,0,359  
72.13,23.86,1.961111111,284.7777778  
74.95,30.19,3.032,137.32  
73.16,22.36,1.37,251.8  
75.84,30.78,3.604347826,125.8695652  
73.52,21.86,1.816666667,228.9166667  
70.44,21.5,2.076,274.08  
69.75,21.36,3.81875,230  
78.05,30.32,0.85625,138.5625
```

Can someone please help me out in drawing streamlines for the irregular wind data?

Comment: can you point us to an example of what a sample plot might look like? maybe http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/streamline.html ?

Comment: Depending on the spacing between stations and observations, and the terrain in between, this may be a poor way to present the data (unless you have to). If you have any kind of hills or forestry, regional pressure gradients between stations, and the spacing is further than the advection distance for the observations, you start having to make big assumptions. Maybe start with quivers() and go from there?

Comment: I've made an attempt to answer a similar question on GIS SE: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175398/how-to-display-wind-data-in-r-with-the-leaflet-package/221137#221137

Answer (score 4):

Like you, I wanted to visualize the same kind of data as streamlnes and I failed to find a function that would do the trick...so I worked up my own crude function:

```
streamlines <- function(x, y, u, v, step.dist=NULL, 
                        max.dist=NULL, col.ramp=c("white","black"), 
                        fade.col=NULL, length=0.05, ...) {

  ## Function for adding smoothed vector lines to a plot. 
  ## Interpolation powered by akima package

  ## step.distance - distance between interpolated locations (user coords)
  ## max.dist - maximum length of interpolated line (user coords)
  ## col.ramp - colours to be passed to colorRampPalette
  ## fade.col - NULL or colour to add fade effect to interpolated line
  ## ... - further arguments to pass to arrows

  ## build smoothed lines using interp function
  maxiter <- max.dist/step.dist
  l <- replicate(5, matrix(NA, length(x), maxiter), simplify=FALSE)
  names(l) <- c("x","y","u","v","col")
  l$x[,1] <- x
  l$y[,1] <- y
  l$u[,1] <- u
  l$v[,1] <- v
  for(i in seq(maxiter)[-1]) {
    l$x[,i] <- l$x[,i-1]+(l$u[,i-1]*step.dist)
    l$y[,i] <- l$y[,i-1]+(l$v[,i-1]*step.dist)
    r <- which(l$x[,i]==l$x[,i-1] & l$y[,i]==l$y[,i-1])
    l$x[r,i] <- NA
    l$y[r,i] <- NA
    for(j in seq(length(x))) {
      if(!is.na(l$x[j,i])) {
        l$u[j,i] <- c(interp(x, y, u, xo=l$x[j,i], yo=l$y[j,i])$z)
        l$v[j,i] <- c(interp(x, y, v, xo=l$x[j,i], yo=l$y[j,i])$z) 
      } 
    }
  }

  ## make colour a function of speed and fade line
  spd <- sqrt(l$u^2 + l$v^2) # speed
  spd <- apply(spd, 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE) # mean speed for each line
  spd.int <- seq(min(spd, na.rm=TRUE), max(spd, na.rm=TRUE), length.out=maxiter)
  cr <- colorRampPalette(col.ramp)
  cols <- as.numeric(cut(spd, spd.int))
  ncols <- max(cols, na.rm=TRUE)
  cols <- cr(ncols)[cols]
  if(is.null(fade.col)) {
    l$col <- replicate(maxiter, cols)
  } else {
    nfade <- apply(!is.na(l$x), 1, sum)
    for(j in seq(length(x))) {
      l$col[j,seq(nfade[j])] <- colorRampPalette(c(fade.col, cols[j]))(nfade[j])
    } 
  }

  ## draw arrows
  for(j in seq(length(x))) {
    arrows(l$x[j,], l$y[j,], c(l$x[j,-1], NA), c(l$y[j,-1], NA), 
           col=l$col[j,], length=0, ...)
    i <- which.max(which(!is.na(l$x[j,]))) # draw arrow at end of line
    if(i>1) {
      arrows(l$x[j,i-1], l$y[j,i-1], l$x[j,i], l$y[j,i], 
             col=l$col[j,i-1], length=length, ...) 
    }
  }

}
```

The function is powered by the interp function in the [akima](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/akima/index.html) package and, with some fiddling, it can produce some half decent visuals:

```html
dat <- "longitude,latitude,windspeed,winddirection  
84.01,20,1.843478261,126.6521739  
77.13,28.48,3.752380952,138.952381  
77.2,28.68,2.413333333,140.2666667  
78.16,31.32,1.994444444,185.0555556  
77.112,31.531,2.492,149.96  
77,28.11,7.6,103  
77.09,31.5,1.752631579,214.8947368  
76.57,31.43,1.28,193.6  
77.02,32.34,3.881818182,264.4545455  
77.15,28.7,2.444,146.12  
77.35,30.55,3.663157895,131.3684211  
75.5,29.52,4.175,169.75  
72.43,24.17,2.095,279.3  
76.19,25.1,1.816666667,170  
76.517,30.975,1.284210526,125.6315789  
76.13,28.8,4.995,126.7  
75.04,29.54,4.09,151.85  
72.3,24.32,0,359  
72.13,23.86,1.961111111,284.7777778  
74.95,30.19,3.032,137.32  
73.16,22.36,1.37,251.8  
75.84,30.78,3.604347826,125.8695652  
73.52,21.86,1.816666667,228.9166667  
70.44,21.5,2.076,274.08  
69.75,21.36,3.81875,230  
78.05,30.32,0.85625,138.5625"

tf <- tempfile()
writeLines(dat, tf)
dat <- read.csv(tf)

library(rgdal) # for projecting locations to utm coords
library(akima) # for interpolation

## add utm coords
xy <- as.data.frame(project(cbind(dat$longitude, dat$latitude), "+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=NAD83"))
names(xy) <- c("easting","northing")
dat <- cbind(dat, xy)

## add u and v coords
dat$u <- -dat$windspeed*sin(dat$winddirection*pi/180)
dat$v <- -dat$windspeed*cos(dat$winddirection*pi/180)


#par(bg="black", fg="white", col.lab="white", col.axis="white")
plot(northing~easting, data=dat, type="n", xlab="Easting (m)", ylab="Northing (m)")
streamlines(dat$easting, dat$northing, dat$u, dat$v, 
            step.dist=1000, max.dist=50000, col.ramp=c("blue","green","yellow","red"), 
            fade.col="white", length=0, lwd=5)
```

[image]

Comment: it's very nice, how disply it in interactive map with leaflet

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this would be enough data to do what you request:

```
 require(plotrix)
 require(maps)
 map("world",xlim=c(69,85),ylim= c(20,35))
 with(dat, 
     vectorField(windspeed, winddirection, longitude, latitude , vecspec="deg") )
```

After staring at the output a bit, I think there may be problems with how I am using that function or with the function itself. The orientations of the arrows seems wrong. Likewise I think the TeachingDemos vector field is not well done, but here is what I get:

```
require(TeachingDemos)
 map("world",xlim=c(69,85),ylim= c(20,35))
 with(dat, my.symbols(x=longitude, y=latitude, 
       symb= ms.arrows, length=windspeed/10, angle=2*pi*winddirection/360))
```

This plot seems to have sufficient variation in direction but the arrow heads seem to vary erratically in size. In any event neither of these plots suggests that this data can be used to construct streamlines. The data is both too sparse and internally contradictory as far as wid direction at adjacent locations.

[image]