# Plotting streamlines for unevenly spaced arrays in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two arrays of n by n indicating U and V velocities. I wish to plot the streamlines.

I am aware this can be done for regularly spaced arrays using [`streamplot`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.streamplot.html). I'm currently working on an array that is relatively close to regularly spaced so the issues are not that big. However, soon I will be working on arrays where the arrays are far from evenly spaced. With the coordinates following curves.

I've looked for a way to plot these but I cannot seem to find any modules. The only two ways I could think of doing it are:

1. approach the actual solution with a regularly spaced grid
2. use a vector field instead of a streamline field (similar to what was done here [Streamlines for irregular spaced wind data in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125598/streamlines-for-irregular-spaced-wind-data-in-r))

My question is if there is a module which I can use and if not, what would be the best approach to achieve a suitable result.